# call back function java

Tags: java, android

I have a class called BuyCoins, within this class I have a method addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection()

```
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.conversion);
    CustomOnItemSelectedListener c = new CustomOnItemSelectedListener(t);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(c);
    //String stockCode=c.getStock();
    //Log.d(TAG,"message");
}
```

This creates a new object that detects which item(product) was selected on the spinner.
I would like to pass this back into the BuyClass. I have attempted to do this with the lines that are commented out, however the value I receive back is a null.

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

...
public String Stock;

...

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

    String selected=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

    switch(selected) {
        case "20 Coins":
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
            "OnItemSelectedListener : " + selected,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            t.setText("$20");
            this.setStock("20Coins");
            break;
   ...
   }

   private void setStock(String s) {
       Stock=s;
   }

   public String getStock() {
       return Stock;
   }

}
```

Comment: `the value I receive back is a null` - if you want to send something back your method must have a return type (your's is void, i.e. nothing), write a value _into_ an object that has been passed as a parameter or write the value into some field that can be read after the method call. Unless you know what you're doing I'd not recommend options 2 and 3 for you (there might be side effects you're not able to deal with).

Comment: Additionally, if you just added the listener, how should `c.getStock();` be able to return _any_ value? `onItemSelected()` can't have been called at that point.

Comment: hi, I am not sure what you are saying.. String stockCode=c.getStock(); returns null. The getStock method has a return type of string

Comment: Just check when `setStock(...)` is being called: it seems like there's only the place in `onItemSelected(...)` so unless you actually selected an item `stock` won't ever be set. However, if you add the listener to a spinner and _immediately_ call `getStock()` aftert that the user can't even attempt to select an item - hence that call _will_ return null. If you want to write the selected stock somewhere pass that "somewhere" (i.e. an instance of some class) to the listener and let it set the stock at that instance.

Comment: it is only called in onItemSelected ... I dont really understand what you mean... in summary what would you suggest I do..The getStock method only gets called once above and not when an item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're querying the listener right after adding it, i.e. the event can't possibly have happend yet. Since you don't know *when* the even is happening (if at all) you'll need to decouple that.

Example (simple pseudo code, just to get you started):

```
class Model {
  String stock;
}

class Listener {
  Model model;

  Listener( Model m) {
    model = m;
  }

  //In your case Component might be the spinner or its parent, depending on the rest of your code
  void onItemSelected( Component c ) {
    m.stock = c.getText();
  }
}
```

And when you create and register the listener:

```
class BuyCoins {
  Model model;  //initialize 

  ...

  void initListeners() {
    spinner.addListener( new Listener(model) );
  }
}
```

Comment: still strugglling.. the addListerner is in addition to spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(c);so if I understand correctly you are adding additional event listener to the spinner

Comment: @the_big_blackbox no `addListener()` would mean `setOnItemSelectedListener()` in your case. As I said it's only pseudo code (in most cases you can add multiple listeners, hence the "add" - but if there is only one listener of a type allowed, "set" is ok as well).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, managed to resolve by adding the following to a subsequent event.

```
public void onBuyCoinButtonClicked(View arg0) {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String product= spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "product : " + product,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Easy workaround